# Why is New-PSSession working? Where do the ApplicationName and ConfigurationName parameters map to?

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I know this is probably a bit unusual for a StackExchange question... but my PowerShell command is working and I can't figure out why!

The below command executes fine and I can connect to the server and run Exchange-flavoured PowerShell commands:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://server.domain.com/PowerShell -credential $credentials
Import-PSSession $session
```

But I can't see a PSSessionConfiguration called "Microsoft.Exchange"...

[image: PSSessionConfigurations]

And I can't see a WinRM listener with a `URLPrefix` called "PowerShell" (as detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters))...

[image]

Where do the `ApplicationName` and `ConfigurationName` properties map to when I call `New-PSSession`? Why is this command working?

Comment: Yes, first of its kind that I've seen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, as I understand it...

I found the answer succinctly summarised in this Stack Overflow question & answer: [Why is the connectionUri different in WSManConnectionInfo object for exchange and windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757809/why-is-the-connectionuri-different-in-wsmanconnectioninfo-object-for-exchange-an)

> Exchange implements its own PowerShell remoting endpoint, which is IIS hosted.

Running `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` shows the list of session configurations available when you connect to the standard **PowerShell** endpoint.

Apparently, specifying the parameters `-ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<FQDN of Exchange 2010 server>/PowerShell/`, when establishing a remote session, connects you to a special **Exchange** endpoint. [Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297932(v=exchg.141).aspx).

Comment: I've never been a fan of `Import-PSSession` as I feel it muddies the water about what's happening where..  Instead of importing the session, try creating the session and invoking the `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` against the session object.  `icm -session $session { Get-PSSessionConfiguration }` - do you get a different result?  I suspect you're getting your local configuration rather than the remote.  My guess is that the Exchange endpoint is configured for full-language mode at the target, and may (or may not) also register to run as a different user.

Comment: The list of PSSessionConfiguration items in the first image is taken from my RDP-ing into the server and running the Get-PSSessionConfiguration command directly on the machine itself. 

The Exchange endpoint is a separate entity from the PowerShell session configurations. I'm assuming "Micosoft.Exchange" is a configuration the Exchange endpoint knows how to interpret.